# Reading from an XML file using JAXB

Tags: java, servlets

I've created an XML file using JAXB and now I'm trying to read from the file I created from a servlet, I don't see any error in the code but the I'm getting HTTP status 500 Error instantiating servlet class , I've debugged but still can't find where the error is , could someone please tell me what's wrong with the way I'm reading the XML file

Servlet :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

@WebServlet
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
ServletException,IOException {
    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        if(request.getParameter("name").equals("lol")){
            out.println("servlet working");
        }
        File file = new File("mvs.xml");
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Movie.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        Movie m= (Movie) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
        System.out.println(m.getFilm());
        out.println("Movies : ");
        List<movieINFO> list=m.getFilm();
        for(movieINFO mINFO:list)
            out.println(mINFO.getId()+" "+mINFO.getMovieName()+"  "
                    +mINFO.getDirector()+" "+mINFO.getReleaseDate()
                    +" "+mINFO.getTrailer());

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

the web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee 
https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
     version="5.0">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>getMovie</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.q1.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>getMovie</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/movieName</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

the index.jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Movie List</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="movieName" method="post">
<h1>Movie List</h1>
<input placeholder="movie name" type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the XML file I'm trying to read from :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<movie>
<film id="10">
    <director>Matthias Schweighöfer</director>
    <genre>Comedy/Action</genre>
    <movieName>Army of Thieves</movieName>
    <releaseDate>29/10/2021</releaseDate>
    <trailer>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ith2WetKXlg</trailer>
</film>
<film id="11">
    <director> Denis Villeneuve</director>
    <genre>Sci-Fi/Adventure</genre>
    <movieName>Dune</movieName>
    <releaseDate>16/09/2021</releaseDate>
    <trailer>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9xhJrPXop4</trailer>
</film>
```

The error that I'm getting when running the servlet :
[image: error1]

[image: error2]

Comment: Do you have a exception with stacktrace or anything in your logs?  Without any detail on what has gone wrong, it's difficult to help you.  All we could really do would be to guess at your problem, but our guesses could turn out to be completely unhelpful to you.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I've edited the question and added the error that I'm getting when running the servlet , hope you could help me please

Comment: Please paste the exception stacktraces as text rather than images, otherwise those people using screenreaders will be unable to help.  That said, it seems the problem is that your web app uses Servlets version 5 and you are running it on a version of Tomcat that does not support Servlets version 5.  Either downgrade your web app to Servlets version 3.1 or upgrade to Tomcat 10.  See also http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html .

Comment: yea the probelm was with the version , worked after switching to tomcat 10 @LukeWoodward